# How to display read more in mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

On the front page of the website, I have the top 5 news articles from my database ordered by date and after 100 characters it says "...Read more". Which works.
How I can add 'Read more' for any article where this 'read more' will appear after a short description of the article???

Here is my Controller:

```
using CBA.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CBA.ViewModels;

namespace CBA.Controllers
{
    public class EventController : Controller
    {
        private ModelEntities db = new ModelEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            EventDetailsViewModel eventDetail = new EventDetailsViewModel();
            MasterEvents events = new MasterEvents();

            eventDetail.Title = events.Title;
            eventDetail.CreatedTime = events.CreatedTime;
            eventDetail.Detail = events.DetailEvent;
            eventDetail.CreatedBy = events.CreatedBy_Id;
            eventDetail.Description = events.ShortDescription;

            return View(db.MasterEvents.ToList());
        }


        public ActionResult View(int id)
        {
            MasterEvents MasterEvents = db.MasterEvents.Find(id);

            return View();
        }



    }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CBA.Models.MasterEvents>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Recruitment - NA Events";
    ViewBag.lnkEvents = "active";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/ContentFrontEnd.cshtml";
}


@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Carousel)
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Content)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div class="blog-post">
                        <h2 class="blog-post-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h2>
                        <p class="blog-post-meta">Created Time @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedTime) <!--by <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy_Id)</a></p>-->
                        <h2 class="blog-post-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</h2>
                        <div class="readmore">
                            <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DetailEvent)
                        </p>
                             </div>
                        <p class="blog-post-meta">Update Time @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedTime)
                        <p>


                            <br />

                            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Read More..." class="btn btn-default" />
                        </p>
                    </div>   
                }


                <nav>
                    <ul class="pager">
                        <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace CBA.Models
{
    public class MasterEvents
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Events Title")]
        [DisplayName("Title")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Short Description")]
        [DisplayName("Short Description")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Details")]
        [DisplayName("Detail Events")]
        public string DetailEvent { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Created Time")]
        public System.DateTime? CreatedTime { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Updated Time")]
        public System.DateTime? UpdatedTime { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Created By")]
        public int? CreatedBy_Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Updated By")]
        public int? UpdatedBy_Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have given the same code for the controller and for the view.
Anyway, why not achieve this trick in Javascript?

Comment: the question is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate each item instance in a form so that when the user clicks the read more input, the hidden textbox which holds the Id of the article will be posted and then you can just retrieve the whole article in the controller and then display it in the view.

```
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
              @using(Html.BeginForm("View", "Event")){
                <div class="blog-post">
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h2>
                    <p class="blog-post-meta">Created Time @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedTime) <!--by <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy_Id)</a></p>-->
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</h2>
                    <div class="readmore">
                        <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DetailEvent)
                    </p>
                         </div>
                    <p class="blog-post-meta">Update Time @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedTime)
                    <p>


                        <br />
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)
                        <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Read More..." class="btn btn-default" />
                    </p>
                </div>   
              }
            }
```